# Can a template class has a templated friend declaration?

Tags: c++, templates, friend

In other words does this code work?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class ImFriendWith {
    int privValue;
    public:
        ImFriendWith(int v): privValue{v} {};
    
    friend class T; // <-- THIS
};

struct Befriended {
    ImFriendWith<Befriended> secret;
    
    Befriended(int v): secret{v} {};
    
    int getValue() { return secret.privValue; }
};

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    Befriended b{42};
    std::cout << "The secret is: " << b.getValue() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to compile it with G++, but it splits out only errors. Also I haven't found anything like my example at https://en.cppreference.com/

**However**...

If I remove the text "class" next to "friend", then it compiles and works like I wanted: it prints "The secret is: 42".

I want to know:

- why it works, and
- is it portable?

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly what you're asking. You posted code that fails to compile, and you know what to change to fix it. So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @Kevin Why it works. I haven't found anybody doing it, and any C++ specification that mentions something like my code. For all what I know it shouldn't work.

Comment: Which version of g++? Making a template parameter a friend is only legal since C++11, has been illegal before. So if you don't have a sufficiently recent compiler (or don't enable a sufficiently ecent standard, e.g. `-std=c++17`), then it will complain about...

Comment: @Kevin I must work my search skills better, but yes it answers :). I'm only a bit surprised I haven't found this anywhere else.

Comment: `friend class T;` is as `void foo(class T);`, it also declare a class (named `T` unrelated to the template parameter) in addition to their usage.